# Use nested value from record as key in Kafka

Tags: apache-nifi

I have some problem with public data on Kafka. I have record to public like this:

```
{
"name": "Jess",
"surname": "Stone",
 "data": {
"mail": "j.stone@gmail.com",
"class": "5",
  "address": {
  "country": "Brasil",
  "city": "Rio de Janeiro"
 }
},
"anotherData": {
"sex": "female",
"code": "1220"
}
}
```

I need set code value as key so I set it like

Message Key Field code
But it doesn't works, i think it is possible that it doesn't work because this value is nested-when I set for example name it works. Maybe you know how can I set these nested value from this record to Message Key Field? I tried something like this: anotherData.code but it doesn't work too...

Comment: please edit your question and provide details in form - what have you tried, expected result, and actual result.

Comment: Moreover, on top of what @daggett said, the JSON can be improved, and the English can be improved